# Amazon S3 - How to transition 1 backup file to Glacier per month

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3

I'm currently storing daily WHM backups of my site on S3 and retaining 10 copies.  According to a LifeCycle rule, backups are deleted after 10 days.

I'm hoping to transition one backup a month to Glacier storage, indefinitely.

None of my searching indicates this to be possible.  I'm hoping to get a shove in the right direction if that's not the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to move that monthly backup to some prefix say  in the same bucket and set up a rule to move this monthly backup to glacier.

Probably if you are sound with python/java/nodejs , you can create a lambda function and schedule it on a monthly basis (say 1st of every month).This lambda function will move your latest backup of the month to the prefix and according to the rule you create for glacier storage ,it will be automatically gets transitioned to Glacier.

Unless I am missing something , here is blog to setup a policy to transfer s3 data to glacier.

[Archiving Amazon S3 Data to Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/)

P.S : Moving an s3 object includes 2 steps-

```
  1. copy object from source to destination (s3 bucket monthly-prefix)
  2. delete original object
```

Comment: Thanks tom!  This is making much more sense to me now but I'm struggling with the lambda.  

Each backup on S3 consists of a folder named YYYY-MM-DD with 2 files inside.  How can I find/access the most recent folder so I can process it using the lambda function called from a CloudWatch rule?

I've been successful testing with single files when the lambda is triggered by an event but this is something different altogether.